# Azure blob storage and stream analytics

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I read what in azure blob very nice save some data for statistics or something else, after it create requests for blob and show statistics to website (dashboard).
But I don't know how to use stream analytics for showing statistics. It is some SDK for create query to blob and generate josn data. Or ... I don't know.
And I have more question about it:

- How to save data to blob (it is json data or something else). I don't
  know format data for it issue.
- How to use stream analytics for create request to blob and after it get data for showing in dashboard.

And maybe you know how to use this technology. Help me please. Thanks, and have a nice day.

Comment: Add the blob as input with the JSON file referenced. Then write a query in Stream Analytisc that will query it.

Comment: @PhucHDuong ok, if I add 10000 files how to create query in Stream Analytics? And selected just some files?

Comment: That's not really recommended because I think you'd have to add each file one by one... Can you combine the file? If it's JSON you can write a script that would join them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Taras - did you get a chance to toy with the Stream Analytics UI?

When you add a blob input you can either add an entire container - which means Stream Analytics will scan the entire container for new files or you can specify a path prefix pattern which will make Stream Analytics look in only that path.

You can also specify tokens such as {date}, {time} on the path prefix pattern to help guide Stream Analytics on the files to read.

Generally speaking - it is highly recommended to use Event Hub as input for the improved latency.

As for output - you can either use Power BI which would give you an interactive dashboard or you can output to some storage (blob, table, SQL, etc...) and build a dashboard on top of that.

You can also try to do one of the walkthroughs to get a feel for Stream Analytics: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-twitter-sentiment-analysis-trends/

Thanks!

Ziv.

Comment: Thanks you, it is exactly what I need.

Comment: @Ziv My scenario is like i have used blob as stream analytic input (Reference Data) along with iotHub stream input. My stream analytic post some alerts to event hub. The problem is when i update blob file (json file), stream analytic doesn't read the latest file. I have some logic written in blob that needs to be apply to generate alerts. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: The Event-Hub approach has one fundamental weakness that blobs overcome: if my iot-device is not always online and reachable, then data points will be dropped. With a blob approach, I can retry until my locally-cached dataset is safely transferred up to a cloud blob, and then start the stream-analytics... Or does Event-Hub have a local (iot-client) queue of several 1MB+?